# Providing an instanceable class's method as a function pointer?

Tags: c++

Here is what I'd like to do. I have a function pointer which wants a function like this:

void func(int a);

so I have a class:

```
 class Foo {
    public:
    void func(int a);
    };

    Foo *foo = new Foo;

    something->setFunction(foo->func);
```

or in my case:

```
testWidget[count] = new TestWidget;
            testWidget[count]->eventMouseClick.addHandler(testWidget[0]->silly);
```

But this gives me:

> Error 5   error C3867:
>   'TestWidget::silly': function call
>   missing argument list; use
>   '&TestWidget::silly' to create a
>   pointer to
>   member    c:\users\josh\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2008\projects\agui\alleg_5\main.cpp   190

Is there a way I could make this work without using a static function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I could make this work without using a static function?

No.  You can't convert a pointer to member function to an ordinary function pointer.

If the callback accepted any callable object (or a `std::function`, for example), then you could bind the object to the member function and pass the result of that; unfortunately, you can't convert that result to an ordinary function pointer, though.

Comment: How could I use std::function in a way where it's as easy for the end user as above?

Comment: You'd need to change `setFunction` to take a `std::function<void(int)>` instead of a `void(*)(int)`.

Comment: (or `boost::function` or `std::tr1::function`)

Comment: is std::tr1::function c++2003 compatible?

Comment: @Milo:  No, it's part of TR1 (hence why it is in the `std::tr1` namespace).  Boost.Function should compile on any C++03 compiler though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me. But the error message from the compiler makes me feel that probably you want something like this `something->setFunction(&foo->func);`

An example might help in case of overloads

```
struct T{
   void func(int){}
   void func(double){}
};


void f(void (T::*f)(int)){}
void f(void (T::*f)(double)){}

int main(){
   void (T::*fi)(int) = &T::func;
   void (T::*fd)(double) = &T::func;

   f(fi);
   f(fd);
}
```